# Textbox for Output in Python (Text-Based Game)

Tags: python

I'd like to redirect output from the Python shell to my Tkinter GUI with a textbox.

For example, clicking on the Inventory in my game will display your supplies in the Python shell. I would like for it to be displayed within the GUI textbox.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: show some code. it is not clear wether you are talking about redirecting *from* or *to* the shell

Answer (score 0):

You can create a handler for your textbox such that:

```
class textbox_handler:
  def __init__(self, text):
    self.data = []
    self.text = text #text is your tk text widget.
  def write(self, s):
    self.data.append(s)
  def print_out(self):
    for line in data:
        self.text.insert('end',line)
```

Then, in your main function:

```
import sys
def main():
  handler = textbox_handler(text1)
  sys.stdout = handler
  print "sample text."
  print "sample text #2."
  print "another sample text."
  #or you can use without setting sys.stdout
  print >>handler, "yet another sample text."
```

Each print statement calls write method of the handler object. You can simply retrieve those strings from handler.data.